# jQuery: fadeOut, shuffle, fadeIn (stops working at shuffle)

Tags: jquery, random, jquery-animate, fade, shuffle

I have an unordered list.  When i click a shuffle button, i need:

1. the items to fade out
2. then randomise
3. then fade back in.

All separate parts of my script work. The animated fade works on it's own, and the shuffle works.  The problem is when shuffle is in the script, that it skips straight to the shuffle, and stops all fade in or out.

Here is my script:

```
$('.vShuffle').click(function(){
    $('.list li').fadeOut(1000).shuffle().fadeIn(1000);                 
});
```

I have also tried this, which will fade out, then i assume it shuffles because it doesn't do anything else after:

```
$('.vShuffle').click(function(){
    $('.list li').fadeOut(1000, function() {                    
        $('.list li').shuffle();
        $('.list li').fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

The shuffle script i'm using is from here, it works fine other than in my chain: http://mktgdept.com/jquery-shuffle

```
(function(d){d.fn.shuffle=function(c){c=[];return this.each(function(){c.push(d(this).clone(true))}).each(function(a,b){d(b).replaceWith(c[a=Math.floor(Math.random()*c.length)]);c.splice(a,1)})};d.shuffle=function(a){return d(a).shuffle()}})(jQuery);
```

Any help would be greatly apprecitated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without doing some substantial debugging I can't know exactly what's going wrong, but I'm guessing the problem has something to do with the following:

```
$('.list li').fadeOut(1000, function() {                    
    $('.list li').shuffle();
    $('.list li').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Do you realize that the code inside the `fadeOut` callback (i.e. the `shuffle()` and `fadeIn()` function calls) is getting run once per every `.list li` element? In other words, if you have 10 elements that match the `.list li` selector, you're actually shuffling and fading in all the `.list li` elements 10 times. That's because `.fadeOut` will be called on every single matching `.list li` element, and therefore its callback will then be called.

Instead, just call `.fadeOut` on the containing `ul` element, and then in the callback call `.fadeIn` on that containing element as well:

```
$('.vShuffle').click(function(){
    $('ul').fadeOut(1000, function() {       
        $('li').shuffle();
        $('ul').fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mdur4/

Comment: This works great.  Thanks.  Just an additional thought, i've been trying.  Is to make each individual li fade in one after the other, i realise this still has the same problem as before, as i fade out the li instead of the ul to start. I've tried this:  `$("li").each(function(i) {       $(this).delay(50*i).fadeIn(1000);
});` which works on it's own, but again no luck in the whole script.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Actually, you have to use it like this:

```
  $('#myUl').fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $('#myUl li').shuffle();
    $('#myUl').fadeIn(1000)
  });
```

Since calling fadeout on all li items leads to n amount of li callback functions to be called. Don't exactly know what the effect of that is.